# Не найдены php файлы

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Я делаю сайт на Php. У меня есть два сервера: расширение для vscode php server(запускает сайт) и wamp server(запускает БД). У меня была проблема с драйвером mysql. Писало, что он не найден. У меня отдельная папка с Php для php server'а и для БД в wamp server. Так вот, я попробовал перекопировать папку php 8.3.0 в папку php для Php server и у меня появились ошибки(приложил скриншот). Но проблема с драйвером исчезла. Как убрать эти ошибки, почему они возникли?

Index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Проверка, если форма входа была отправлена
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];

  // Проверка учетных данных (замените на свой механизм аутентификации)
  if ($username === "admin" && $password === "adminpass") {
      // Устанавливаем сессию для администратора
      $_SESSION["admin"] = $username;
      header("Location: admin.php");
      exit();
  } elseif ($username === "user" && $password === "userpass") {
      // Устанавливаем сессию для обычного пользователя
      $_SESSION["user"] = $username;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Мир Обоев</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/table.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/fonts/fonts.css" />
    <link rel="preload" href="../css/common.css" as="style">
    <script src="../js/login.js" > </script>

  </head>

  <body> 

       <?php require "elements/header.php" ?>

       <div class="container">

          <?php require "elements/menu.php"?>

          <?php require "elements/login-form.php"?>

          <?php require "elements/content.php"?>

       </div>

        <?php require "elements/footer.php"?>
        

  </body>
</html>
```

table.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "миробоев";

try {
    // Создаем подключение
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // Устанавливаем режим ошибок PDO в исключения
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Пример выполнения запроса
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM обои";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    // Обрабатываем результат
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка подключения: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// Закрываем соединение
$conn = null;
?>

<table>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2">Товар</th>
  <th>Страна</th>
  <th>Ширина</th>
  <th>Артикул</th>
  <th>Цена</th>
  <th>Количество</th>
  <th>Итого</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите ошибку на русский и поймете, что не так. Останется просто проверить пути

Comment: Так дело в том, что с одним php оно нормально работает, но не видит драйвер, а с другим Php не грузит файлы, но зато видит драйвер... С путями все в порядке

Comment: Замените импорт с elements/header.php на ../elements/header.php

Comment: Все, спасибо, заработало.

Comment: Так что пути у вас кривые были ) ошибка всегда правильная и надо доверять отладчику

Comment: Ну на одной версии эти пути работали, на другой нет. Вот это странно.

Comment: Они не могли работать при такой же структуре папок и файлов. Видимо при копировании, что то не туда положили

Comment: @SwaD предлагаю все таки ответ написать ответом, что бы было достаточно понимания :) И вопрос не оставался висеть без пометки о том, что решено

Comment: @StepanTurbasov тут отвечать нечего, а сам вопрос стоит закрыть как опечатка